# How to add plugin Migz-Remux container to a stack

Tags: plugins, stack

I am using FFMPEG - FFBATCH version 3.0.1 on Windows 10 home.

I get an error message when converting an MP4 to an MKV: Subtitle codec 94213 is not supported. The solution would be to add the Migz-Remux container plugin to the stack. However, I can't find the plugin and I have no idea what a stack is and how to add it within FFBATCH.

I use the preset

```
-map 0 -c: v libx265 -preset veryfast -tune fastdecode -crf 25 -r 23 -vf "scale=1280:720" -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 192K -c:s copy
```